# javascript functions with json object parameter

Tags: parameter-passing, javascript

If I have a number of functions that take json object parameters, does it make any difference whether I assign them to a variable before using them inside the function:

```
Function doSomething(data){
var abc = data;

abc.filter….etc.

}
```

Vs.

```
Function doSomething(data){

Data.filter….etc

}
```

is one way better than the other?

Comment: In your second code snipped, your parameter is "data" (lower-case "d") but the code references "Data" (upper-case "d").  JavaScript is case-sensitive. (Well also of course you used "Function" ...)

Comment: It is completely redundant to do that.

Comment: Pointy - it was a typo but thanks for noting that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes no difference and it your example, the new variable is redundant. It is good practice not to create extra variables. It might be useful to do this if your JSON is heavily nested.

```
data = { foo: { bar: { baz: [] } } }

function doSomething(data) {
  var innerData = data.bar.baz;
  for(var i=0; i<innerData.length; i+) {
    // Whatever.
  }     
}
```

This will save you having to reference `data.foo.bar.baz` all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is better not to create the useless extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely redundant to create the `abc` variable in the first example.

Consider how it's really evaluated:

```
function doSomething() {
    var data = arguments[0];
    var abc = data; //why?
}
```